# How to create a column based on condition of a column value contain in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

[image: example data table]

I want to create category column based on value of measure type column,
i.e. if any of the value of measure type corresponding to sr_num has dispatches then i want it to
categorize as D and if it has activities then categorize as A

I have tried below, but it didnt work:

```
select t*,
case when measuretype =  'dispatches' then 'D'
else 'A' end as category
from t
```

Comment: i have tried with case when statement but it didn't work because i need to aggregate it srnum level

Comment: Include your attempt(s) in the question; [edit] them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions.  One method is:

```
 select t.*,
        (case when sum(case when measureType = 'Dispatches' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by sr_num) > 0
              then 'D' else 'A'
         end) as category
 from t;
```

Or, given your sample data, you can use this simpler version:

```
select t.*,
       max(left(measureType, 1)) over (partition by sr_num) as category
from t;
```